# Можно ли в Windows-10 Home отключить некоторые клавиши?

Tags: windows, администрирование, windows-10

Дoбрый день!

Есть Windows-10 Home и есть некоторое приложение, в котором я постоянно набираю текст. Проблема в том, что иногда я промахиваюсь по клавишам и попадаю на соседние клавиши. А в приложении сделано так, что многие клавиши имеют еще какие-то (системные) значения. И приложение либо закрывается, либо начинает выполнять какие-то операции мне сейчас не нужные. В связи с этим я хотел-бы отключить нажатие некоторых клавиш на уровне Windows. Например, чтобы при нажатии клавиши Tab код табуляции не передавался в приложение. Возможно ли сделать такое в Windows-10 Home? И если возможно, то как? Переписать драйвер клавиатуры не предлагать, но можно ткнуть меня в уже написанный драйвер клавиатуры с такой функциональностью.

Спасибo.

Comment: Переписать/перенастроить приложение не вариант?

Comment: @andreymal [Переписать/перенастроить] Не вариант, иначе бы я не спрашивал. Приложение не мое и древнее как фекалии мамонта. Да и просто интересно, в винде сейчас все настраивается, неужели нельзя программно отключить отдельные клавиши?

Comment: _в винде сейчас все настраивается_ - хорошо пошутил

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Имеется ввиду "много чего настраивается по сравнению со старыми версиями винды".

Comment: Можно в реестре переназначить клавиши. Например, у меня на ноуте AltGr переназначена на Alt. Я делал вручную, но есть и спец. утилиты.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Спасибо, посмотрю.